# Get elements from dropbox using selenium and bs4?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i would like to get the elements or the elements-links from this page
https://irglobal.com/advisors/
from the "Firm" select box

So at the end i would like to have:
https://irglobal.com/advisors/?firm=4i-advisory-services
https://irglobal.com/advisors/?firm=a-c-legal
and so on

I tried to get the element for this select box using the following code:

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  WAIT = 1  
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = "https://irglobal.com/ advisors/"
  print(f"Working for {link}")  
  driver.get (link)     
  time.sleep(WAIT) 
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')      
  tmp = soup.find("span", {"class": "select2-selection select2-selection--single"})   
  print(tmp.prettify())
  
  driver.quit()
```

But the element i can find is only a span-element and no select-element which is was expecting:

```
<span aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-firm-container" class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" tabindex="0">
 <span aria-readonly="true" class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-firm-container" role="textbox">
  <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">
   Select
  </span>
  </span>
 </span>
 <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
  <b role="presentation">
  </b>
 </span>
</span>
```

How can i get the elements / the element-links from this select-box on the website?

Hello - i would like to get the elements or the elements-links from this page
https://irglobal.com/advisors/
from the "Firm" select box

So at the end i would like to have:
https://irglobal.com/advisors/?firm=4i-advisory-services
https://irglobal.com/advisors/?firm=a-c-legal
and so on

I tried to get the element for this select box using the following code:

```
import time
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  WAIT = 1  
  print(f"Checking Browser driver...")
  os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = '0' 
  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})    
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)    
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)         
  
  link = "https://irglobal.com/ advisors/"
  print(f"Working for {link}")  
  driver.get (link)     
  time.sleep(WAIT) 
  soup = BeautifulSoup (driver.page_source, 'lxml')      
  tmp = soup.find("span", {"class": "select2-selection select2-selection--single"})   
  print(tmp.prettify())
  
  driver.quit()
```

But the element i can find is only a span-element and no select-element which is was expecting:

```
<span aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-labelledby="select2-firm-container" class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" tabindex="0">
 <span aria-readonly="true" class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-firm-container" role="textbox">
  <span class="select2-selection__placeholder">
   Select
  </span>
  </span>
 </span>
 <span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation">
  <b role="presentation">
  </b>
 </span>
</span>
```

How can i get the elements / the element-links from this select-box on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the values from the ***Firm*** dropdown you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://irglobal.com/advisors/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.select2-selection__rendered#select2-firm-container > span"))).click()
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.select2-results__options#select2-firm-results li")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://irglobal.com/advisors/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='select2-selection__rendered' and @id='select2-firm-container']/span"))).click()
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='select2-results__options' and @id='select2-firm-results']//li")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['4i Advisory Services', 'A &amp; C Legal', 'A van Tuijn', 'A&amp;B Consultants: Mohamed Badr &amp; Partners', 'A&amp;Co Law', 'AAC Kenya', 'Abacus Seychelles Limited', 'ABCF', 'Abogados Martinez Serna', 'Abou Farhat Law Offices', 'Abousleiman &amp; Co', 'ABV Solicitors', 'ACCEL IP Law', 'ACTAH', 'ACURIS Rechtsanwälte', 'ADDAX Avocats', 'Adebola Sobanjo &amp; Company', 'Adeniji Kazeem &amp; Co.', 'adesse anwälte', 'advocatio Attorneys at Law Grabher Dür', 'Advokatfirman ReklamJuridik AB', 'AE Business Advisors', 'Aegis Interaktif Asia', 'Aequitas Law LLP', 'Aequo', 'Africa Integrity', 'Afxentis Zemenides Financial Services Ltd', 'AG Singapore', 'Agio Legal', 'Ahmed Ghattour &amp; Co.', 'AHNSE Law Offices', 'Airwallex', 'Akyianu and Associates&nbsp;', 'AL Partners', 'Al Suwaiket &amp; Al Busaiyes', 'Aldrich Services LLP', 'Aliant Finland', 'Aliant LLP', 'Alias Consulting', 'Allen Barron, Inc.', 'Alliance Trust Company', 'ALMA Law', 'ALMT Legal, Advocates &amp; Solicitors', 'ALTIUS', 'Alturas Law Group', 'Alumni', 'Amani Law Firm', 'Amável Calhau &amp; Associados, SROC, Lda.', 'AMG Mylonas &amp; Associates, LLC', 'AMPACC Law Group, PLLC', 'Andes Glacier CPA Limited, Certified Public Accountants', 'Andreae Associates', 'Andreas Demetriades &amp; Co LLC', 'Anggraeni and Partners', 'Anhad Law', 'Antaxius Advocaten', 'Antonio M. Varvaro Legal Consultants DMCC', 'Anwälte am Dom', 'Aoki Suzuki Accounting Co.', 'AQUIJE CHUNG &amp; ASOCIADOS', 'Arad, Luxenburg and Co.', 'Arco Abogados', 'ARGO Audit Ltd', 'Arnold Hill &amp; Co LLP', 'ASP Law Office', 'Aspen Trust Group', 'ASTRA ADVOKATER', 'Ateus', 'Athena Chambers', 'Athos Group', 'Atlas Consulting PC', 'Audalis Kohler Punge &amp; Partner mbB', 'Audrey Grey', 'Avila Law', 'AZ y Asociados, S.L.', 'AZZUR PORTUGAL', 'B&amp;M Advocates', 'Bacciardi Partners', 'Baigel Corp', 'Baker Law', 'Baluarte', 'BANCO FISCAL', 'Baraona Marshall &amp; Cia.', 'Barcellos Tucunduva Advogados', 'Barnes Roffe LLP', 'Baro Alto', 'Barta, Jones &amp; Foley, PLLC', 'Başgül', 'Bavelaar Attorneys at Law', 'BBA Law Group', 'BCF', 'BDO Advisory Services', 'Beer &amp; Steinmair Rechtsanwälte OG', 'Belgore, Olufadi &amp; Co.', 'Bell Legal Group', 'Bell Rock', 'Bennett Thrasher', 'Beresford Capital', 'Berkowitz Pollack Brant Advisors + CPAs', 'Berninzon &amp; Benavides Abogados', 'BERTANI', 'BG2V', 'BGJC Consulting Pvt Ltd', 'Bignon De Keyser', 'Bind', 'BINGH Advocaten', 'Bizilance Legal Consultants', 'Blackgold Law Firm', 'Blanchard, Krasner &amp; French', 'Blaser Mills Law', 'BloomBudd LLP', 'Blume Christen Polinske Partnerschaft mbB', 'Blumenthal Richter &amp; Sumet', 'Bob Low &amp; Co', 'Boccadutri Studio Legale', 'Bodie Law', 'Bona Law PC', 'Bonn &amp; Schmitt', 'Bonn Steichen &amp; Partners', 'Bordianu &amp; Associates', 'BORY &amp; ASSOCIÉS, LAWYERS', 'Bos Law', 'BP&amp;A, Finance and Business consulting', 'BPG Group', 'BPiON', 'BPV', 'Bramelle Partners', 'Bratschi AG', 'Braumiller Law Group, PLLC', 'Brickett Consulting', 'BROADHURST LLC', 'BrownWinick Law Firm', 'Bryn Law Group', 'BSA Ahmad Bin Hezeem &amp; Associates LLP', 'BSB Attorneys at Law', 'Buckingham, Doolittle &amp; Burroughs, LLC', 'Bufete B. Buigas', 'Burke Costanza &amp; Carberry LLP', 'Burton Law Firm, PC', 'Bustamante Fabara', 'Bustos Tax &amp; Legal', 'Butler Snow LLP', 'Buyssens Advocaten Sociaal Recht', 'Buzády &amp; Udvari Law Firm', 'CA.sg PAC', 'Cabinet Avocats &amp; Associés Abayazid &amp; Abdourahman', 'Cabinet Comptable &amp; Fiscal Deramchi', 'Caceres Torres', 'Campos Galván y Abogado', 'CAMYA', 'CANAHUATE ROUCHÈS', 'Cannizzo, Ortíz y Asociados, S.C.', 'Canosa Abogados', 'Caplin &amp; Drysdale, Chartered', 'Carbert Waite LLP', 'Cardium Law', 'Carey, Douglas, Kessler &amp; Ruby, PLLC', 'Carlos Picos Consultora', 'CARRION ADVOGADOS', 'Carvallo Family Law', 'Cast Global Group', 'Caystone', 'CBIZ Forensic Consulting Group', 'CBM Audit &amp; Conseil', 'CCF AUDIT', 'CCK Strategies, PLLC', 'CCP Group of Companies', 'CDR Legal', 'Cederblad &amp; Co', 'Central Mass Mediation &amp; Arbitration', 'Cerejeira Namora, Marinho Falcão', 'CGE - Centre Général d’Expertises Comptables Sàrl', 'CGM Advogados', 'Chapman Eastway', 'Charltons', 'Chevez Ruiz Zamarripa y Cía, SC', 'Chin &amp; Associates, Solicitors', 'Chuhak &amp; Tecson, P.C.', 'Clark Hill PLC', 'Clark Wilson LLP', 'Clayton &amp; McKervey', 'Clement T. Maynard &amp; Company', 'Clio', 'CMJ &amp; PARTNERS', 'CNPLaw LLP', 'Cole Schotz', 'Colley Intelligence', 'Colman Coyle', 'Colter Carswell &amp; Asociados, S.C.', 'Comptafid Benelux NV', 'Condon Advisory Group', 'Confidor', 'Conn Maciel Carey', 'Corona &amp; Nepote Abogados', 'Corpag', 'Corrieri Cilia', 'Coyle &amp; Co Chartered Accountants', 'CR Advocates LLP', 'Crady Jewett McCulley &amp; Houren LLP', 'Cranfill Sumner LLP', 'CreditCheck Partners', 'Creel Abogados', 'Croma', 'Crowe Soberman LLP', 'CTA Law Firm', 'Cummins Beaudoin Lawyers', 'Curran Antonelli, LLP', 'Current Consulting Group', 'Daiichi Legal Professional Corporation', 'Daniels Law Group', 'Danovi &amp; Partners', 'Dar Alnuzum', 'David Teixeira De Azevedo Advogados', 'DCSL Corporate Services Limited', 'de Bedin &amp; Lee studio legale associato', 'De Clercq Lawyers and Notary', 'De Facto Juristbyrå AB', 'Deep &amp; Far Attorneys-at-Law', 'DEL Partners', 'Delphi', 'DeMarco Law, PLLC', 'Densborn Blachly LLP', 'Dezan Shira &amp; Associates', 'DFK Oswin Griffiths Carlton', 'DH Kemp', 'Diaz Reus', 'Dickie, McCamey &amp; Chilcote, P.C.', 'Diener Advisory', 'Diligence International Group', 'Dipchand LLP', 'Diri Sevi Mergen', 'DLP Dr Lewandowski &amp; Partners', 'Dojima Law Office', 'Donato Legal Pty Ltd', 'Donovan Hatem LLP', 'Douglas Home and Co', "Dowell's Advisory Services Inc", 'Doyles Construction Lawyers', 'DSC LEGAL Rechtsanwaltsgesellschaft mbH', "DTS Duijn's Tax Solutions", 'Duane Morris', 'Duffy &amp; Young LLC', 'DUFOUR – Advokatur', 'Dunalegal', 'Dunning Rievman &amp; MacDonald LLP', 'Durukan + Partners', 'EBS', 'Edwards Bradley PC', 'Egan Nelson', 'Einbinder &amp; Dunn LLP', 'Elisabetta Cicigoi', 'Ellen van Swaaij Familierecht', 'Ellisons Solicitors', 'Eluchans Abogados', 'EmergeCounsel', 'Emmanuel Jacques Almosnino law firm', 'ENDEMANN.SCHMIDT', 'Environmental General Counsel PC', 'eosedge Legal', 'Ernesto Velarde Danache, Inc', 'Ersoy Bilgehan', 'Escobar y Gorostieta, SC Lawyers', 'Eshwars House of Corporate &amp; IPR Laws', 'Espinoza &amp; Heskia Abogados', 'Essex Richards, P.A.', 'Eugene Thuraisingam LLP', 'eureos gmbh steuerberatungsgesellschaft rechtsanwaltsgesellschaft', 'Everest Law', 'Everest Legal', 'Evergent Law', 'EWP Business Consulting', 'FairValue', 'Farage Andrews Law Practice', 'FDE Legal', 'Federal Practice Group', 'FERIA TANTOCO DAOS (Feria Law)', 'Ferraz de Camargo Advogados', 'FIDAG', 'FIDASmart', 'Fiduchi', 'Film &amp; Ink Law Group', 'Finpartner', 'Finvision', 'Fischer &amp; Partner', 'Fitzroy Tax Services', 'Fleming Lake Group, Inc.', 'ForsheyProstok, LLP', 'Fox Rothschild LLP', 'FrancisGrey', 'Frazier &amp; Deeter', 'Fredrikson &amp; Byron P.A.', 'Freitas &amp; Weinberg LLP', 'French Law Group LLC', 'Friedman &amp; Springwater LLP', 'ftl', 'Fullerton Law Chambers LLC', 'Furriela Advogados', 'Füsthy &amp; Mányai Law Office', 'FYLGIA', 'G.C. Consultants, Inc.', 'GAD Legal, LLC', 'GALAHAD cabinet d’avocats', 'Galion', 'Gall Solicitors', 'Gallego Abogados', 'Gallivan White Boyd', 'Galvan Abogados', 'Gálvez, Risso, Zegarra &amp; Asociados', 'Garber &amp; Co', 'GARCIA BLANCO Abogados SLP', 'Garcia Monroy &amp; Asociados', 'Gardiner Roberts LLP', 'Garlicke &amp; Bousfield Inc', 'Gattuso Bouchard Mazzone', 'Gauci &amp; Partners Advocates', 'Gebauer Stein Rechtsanwälte Avocats PartGmbB', 'Geeta Maharaj Law', 'Gekko advisoryNOW', 'General Counsel, P.C.', 'Genome Lawyers', 'Georges Leser Attorney-at-Law', 'Gershoni Co.', 'Gertsburg Licata', 'GESSEL', 'Gessler Blue LLC', 'Gideon Koren &amp; Co.', 'Gilad Berman Law Firm &amp; Notary', 'Gilligan Sheppard', 'Gipson Hoffman &amp; Pancione', 'GKR Legal', 'Glaser Weil Fink Howard Avchen &amp; Shapiro LLP', 'Godwin Attorneys', 'Goldenaudit Cía. Ltda', 'Goldenberg Schneider, LPA', 'Golenbock Eiseman Assor Bell &amp; Peskoe LLP', 'GONZÁLEZ TAPIA ABOGADOS', 'Gordinier, Kang &amp; Kim LLP', 'Gordon Law', 'Gould Law', 'GrahamThompson', 'Grassi', 'Gravis Law', 'Grazer Treuhand Steuerberatung GmbH &amp; Partner KG', 'Graziotto Legal - International Law Firm', 'Greco Vitali Associati', 'Green and Spiegel', 'Greenbaum Law Firm', 'Greenwald Doherty LLP', 'Grinhaus Law Firm', 'Grunfeld, Desiderio, Lebowitz, Silverman &amp; Klestadt LLP', 'Guanes, Heisecke &amp; Piera', 'Guerra Gomez', 'Gulapa Law Office', 'Günay Legal', 'gunnercooke llp', 'Güzeldere Balkan Göçen Attorney Partnership', 'GUZMÁN &amp; MOLINA, Abogados', 'GvW Graf von Westphalen', 'H. L. Willis &amp; Associates', 'Häckl Treuhand GmbH, Steuerberatungsgesellschaft Schondorf - Munich', 'Halabi &amp; Associés', 'Hammond-Partnership', 'Hanotiau &amp; van den Berg', 'Harbour Chambers BVI', 'Harris Cook, LLP', 'Harrison Law, PLLC', 'Harry Elias Partnership LLP', 'Hartwell Thalacker, LTD.', 'Hassouna &amp; Abou Ali', 'Hatstone Trust Company (BVI) Limited', 'Hawks Villafranca Law, PLLC', 'Hawksford Ireland Limited', 'Haytham Al-Nasser Certified Public Accountants &amp; Auditors', 'Health Law Consultancy', 'HELLSTRÖM Law', 'Hera Family Office', 'Herrington Carmichael LLP', 'Heuser Recht Und Steuern', 'HHK', 'Hibiya - Nakata', 'Hicks Thomas', 'Higuchi &amp; Partners, LPC', 'Hinman Straub', 'HLG', 'HMB Accountants', 'Hoberman &amp; Lesser CPAs, LLP', 'Holland &amp; Knight', "Holmes O'Malley Sexton LLP", 'Holst, Advokater', 'Hon. Lady Justice Joyce Aluoch', 'Honmachi International Law Office, P.C.', 'HQ Lawyers', 'Hristescu &amp; Partners', 'Hussain Al Shemsi Chartered Accountants, Ajman', 'Hutabarat Halim &amp; Rekan Lawyers', 'Hutchinson and Bloodgood LLP', 'HW Group Inc.', 'HyC Consulting Empresarial SL', 'HYS &amp; Co. Advocaten', 'I. M. Typographos &amp; Co LLC', 'I. Mandelenis &amp; Partners Law Office', 'IAS Partners', 'IFG Consulting Ltd.', 'ILLOUZ AVOCATS', 'Illume Advisory', 'Illume Investigations', 'IM Certified Public Accountants Limited', 'Imara Trust Company (Mauritius) Limited', 'Independence Capital', 'Independent Insurance Managers Inc.', 'Independia Law Firm AB', 'India Law Offices LLP', 'InfoCapital N.V. Advisory &amp; Management', 'Infocredit Group Ltd', 'Innovate Capital Law', 'Integrated Accounting Group', 'Interexpert', 'Invictus Law', 'IOM Law', 'IPG Lex &amp; Tax', 'IPO Pang Xingpu', 'ISFIN', 'Ivins, Phillips &amp; Barker', 'Ivory Advocates', 'Jack A. Alli, Sons &amp; Co.', 'James A. Schmidt, Esq. Tax and Business Law', 'James Conomos Lawyers', 'Jaramillo Dávila Abogados', 'Jardaneh Law Firm', 'JCPartners PAC', 'Jeremy Levi CPA', 'Johnson &amp; Pump', 'Johnston Clem Gifford PLLC', 'Jovović Mugoša &amp; Vuković', 'Joyce A. Tan &amp; Partners LLC', 'JungjinSerim Accounting Corp', 'Jural Acuity', 'Jurinter legal firm', 'K.M Chan &amp; Co., CPA', 'K&amp;K Advocates', 'K&amp;S Partners', 'Kalantar Business Law Group (KBLG)', 'Kaleo Legal', 'Kallas Law Firm', 'Kaplan Legal Services, LLC', 'Karastoyanov, Mitkov &amp; Associates Law Office', 'Karimi &amp; Associates Law Firm', 'Katz, Sapper &amp; Miller', 'KC Legal', 'Kenneth Reich Law, LLC', 'KIAA, LLP', 'King &amp; King Chartered Accountants', 'Kılınç Law &amp; Consulting', 'KJ Partners LLP', 'KLA', 'KN Legal', 'KNAV', 'Koffels Solicitors &amp; Barristers', 'KP Law', 'Kreindler &amp; Kreindler LLP', 'Krish Maniam &amp; Co', 'Kroll GmbH', 'KSSP Kuryło Sudolski Szrek', 'KTK Advocates', 'Kulat Law', 'Kuroda Law Offices', 'KW KRUK AND PARTNERS LAW FIRM LP', 'L J Soldinger Associates, LLC', 'L.A. Monzón y Asociados', 'Lajer Law Firm', 'LakeLaw', 'Lanfranchi Law Firm', 'Lang &amp; Rahmann', 'Langlois Lawyers, LLP', 'Law Office Turnstone', 'Law Offices of Jeffery M. Leving, Ltd.', 'Law Offices of Peter Katz, LLC', 'Law Tax', 'Law&amp;Pepper Advocaten', 'Le &amp; Tran Law Corporation', 'Leahy Lewin Lowing Sullivan Lawyers', 'LEGAL ASEAN', 'LEGALLY.SMART', 'Legem Attorneys at Law, SC', 'LEGORA Ltd.', 'LEIALTA', 'Leman Management', 'LexCase', 'LexCounsel', 'Lexel Juridique &amp; Fiscal', 'LG Firm, S.C.', "Liliana Bakayoko - Avocat d'affaires international", 'Links &amp; Gains Law Firm', "Lippitt O'Keefe Gornbein, PLLC", 'LithurBrew &amp; Company', 'LITREDI S.C', 'LNP Attorneys', 'Loewenberg Psarris Workplace Law LLP', 'Looper Goodwine P.C.', 'Loren &amp; Kean Law', 'Luiz Gomes &amp; Associados', 'Lundgrens', 'M&amp;S Accountancy &amp; Taxation Ltd', 'Magnusson Minds Advokatbyrå AB', 'Maharaj Mohammed &amp; Co', 'Malone &amp; Co', 'Manatt, Phelps &amp; Phillips, LLP', 'Mandanex Capital Pty Ltd', 'Mandelenis &amp; Partners Law Firm', 'Mani Chengappa &amp; Mathur', 'Manolis Eglezos &amp; Associates', 'Manzano Abogados', 'Maprima', 'Marccus Partners Mabel &amp; Associates, Attorneys at Law', 'Mark Copeland Lawyers', 'Marsal Law', 'Martin Kenney &amp; Co', 'Martinot Abogados', 'Martyn Fiddler Aviation &amp; Assets', 'MARY JOYCE CARLSON, ESQ.', 'Massey LLP', 'Mata-Perez, Tamayo and Francisco', 'McBurneys Chartered Accountants &amp; Business Advisors', 'McCarthy, Lebit, Crystal &amp; Liffman Co., LPA', 'McGuire, Craddock &amp; Strother, P.C.', 'McLane Middleton', 'McMAN Ooijevaar: International Trade and Customs', 'McW Todman &amp; Co.', 'MDDP Michalik Dłuska Dziedzic and Partners', 'MegaGroup', 'MehaffyWeber', 'Meijer Advocaten en Belastingadviseurs B.V.', 'Meilin Law', 'Mejia y Asociados Abogados Especializados S.A.S', 'MELCHERS Rechtsanwälte', 'Mellius', 'Mendoza &amp; Pangan', 'Messina Incorporated', 'Messner Reeves LLP', 'METIS Rechtsanwälte PartG mbB', 'MEYER-KÖRING', 'MFR Fontana Ros Legal &amp; Tax Advisors', 'MG Advogados', 'MHPA LLP', 'Middle East Alliance Legal Consultancy', 'Mifsud &amp; Mifsud', 'Millikin Intellectual Property Law PLLC.', 'Mirkwood Evans Vincent', 'Mishcon de Reya', 'MJM Barristers &amp; Attorneys', 'Monarch Solicitors', 'Montgomery &amp; Associados', 'Moore Barlow LLP', 'Mora &amp; Vazquez Asociados, S.C.', 'Moreno &amp; Arjona – Bureau', 'Morrison, Sherwood, Wilson &amp; Deola, PLLP', 'Moyal &amp; Simon Law S.a.r.L', 'MTR Rechtsanwälte', 'Mul &amp; Co', 'Mundkur Law Partners', 'Murphy Business', 'Murray Attorneys at Law', 'Mushoriwa Pasi Corporate Attorneys', 'MV Legal', 'MXGA, Mexico Global Alliance.', 'MYBA', 'MZLS', 'N.D Alfonso &amp; Co', 'N.W.Bernstein &amp; Associates, LLC', 'Nakamoto &amp; Partners', 'Nangwala, Rezida &amp; Co. Advocates', 'Nayla Charabaty Advocates &amp; Legal Consultants', 'Nchito &amp; Nchito Advocates', 'NetDocuments', 'Nexia Insolv Limited', 'NGL Legal', 'Niall Tierney', 'Nicholas Ktenas &amp; Co LCC', 'Nimbus Consultancy', 'Nina Boteva Law Office', 'NKO Law Office', 'NLD Abogados', 'NMK &amp; Co LLP Chartered Accountants', 'NOA', 'Nordeq Management A/S', 'NOTARIA PUBLICA 98', 'Nusantara Legal Partnership', 'Nyiha, Mukoma &amp; Company Advocates', 'OBLIN Rechtsanwälte GmbH', 'Occam Research Services LLP', 'ODI Law Firm - Slovenia', 'Offit│Kurman', 'Ogier Leman Solicitors', 'Oldham, Li &amp; Nie', 'Oller Abogados', 'OLM Law Advocates LLP', 'ONC Lawyers', 'Onyx Partners Ltd.', 'Optimum Accounting Services Co., Ltd', 'Orit Hayoun Law Firm', 'Ortiz Hidalgo y Hernández S.C.', 'Ostermann &amp; Partners LLP', 'Oxygene IP', 'Oyagbola Chambers', 'PAC Auditors', 'Pacific Crest Law Partners, LLP', 'Pagecorp Group', 'Palli Law Firm', 'Pamir Law Group', 'Panalitix', 'PAOLETTI LAW GROUP', 'Pardini &amp; Asociados', 'Park Place Corporate Finance', 'Parra Rodríguez Abogados', 'Paul &amp; Hassan', 'Paul Beare Ltd', 'Payton &amp; Associates, LLC', 'PD Audit', 'PD Law Offices', 'Peake Law Group', 'Peduti Advogados', 'Peer Legal', 'Perun Consultants', 'Petrony Law, LLC', 'Phoenix Legal', 'Pichard &amp; Associés', 'Planning Assessors', 'PlaveKoch', 'Ponte Andrade &amp; Casanova', 'Potomac Law Group, PLLC', 'Prakash Sachin &amp; Co.', 'Premier Financial Services Limited', 'Prepelitchi Abogados', 'Price Bailey Chartered Accountants', 'Primum Law', 'Probst Partner AG', 'Professional Trust', 'Protzman Law', 'Prudential Public Accounting Corporation', 'Pushor Mitchell LLP', 'Python', 'Quadrant Law', 'Quadros &amp; Quadros Advocates', 'Quattlebaum, Grooms &amp; Tull PLLC', 'Quijano &amp; Associates', 'QUORUM', 'R.L. Jennings &amp; Associates', 'Railas Attorneys Ltd.', 'Ravet &amp; Associés', 'RechtStaete', 'Reef - Rechtsanwälte', 'Regan Solicitors', 'Regard Law Group PLLC', 'Reichert Reichert', 'Rennó Penteado Sampaio Advogados', 'Rentsch Partner Ltd.', 'Rexon Nainggolan &amp; Rekan', 'RGD Legal', 'Rhein Schirato &amp; Meireles', 'Rice Reuther Sullivan &amp; Carroll', 'Rich May Law', 'Richelieu Avocats', 'RIMBUN', 'RiSiKo Consulting LLP', 'Ritch &amp; Conolly', 'RKKW - KWAŚNICKI, WRÓBEL &amp; Partnerzy', 'Robalino', 'Robert Fleming Lawyers', 'Rodey, Dickason, Sloan, Akin &amp; Robb, P.A.', 'Rodríguez Rueda, S.C.', 'Rojkowicz Skoblenko i Partnerzy', 'Rosenberg &amp; Estis, P.C.', 'rothpartners', 'RP Legal &amp; Tax', 'RPG Crouch Chapman', 'RSM Malta', 'RUF UND SCHLENKER', 'rugekrömer', 'RumbergerKirk', 'Rushing &amp; Guice', 'Russell Bedford SITAX', 'RW Group', 'S.K. Singhi &amp; Partners LLP', 'S.U.Khan Associates Corporate &amp; Legal Consultants', 'S&amp;P Söffing Kranz', 'SAGIURE LEGAL', 'SALIHIN', 'Salvador Llanillo &amp; Bernardo', 'Sánchez Devanny', 'Sanli Pastore &amp; Hill', 'Sarrazin+Plourde', 'Savitt Bruce &amp; Willey LLP', 'Saward Dawson Chartered Accountants', 'SC Legal', 'Schaffer &amp; Partner', 'Scherzer International', 'SCHNEIDER GROUP', 'Schuiteman Corporate Finance', 'SCHULTE Rechtsanwaltsgesellschaft mbH', 'Schürmann Rosenthal Dreyer Partnerschaft von Rechtsanwälten mbB', 'Schwarz &amp; Partner', 'Schwarz Law Partners LLP', 'SCR Abogados', 'sdh attorneys at law', 'SDR Associates', 'Seeds of Law', 'SELARL DNA NOTAIRES', 'Selepey, Volkovetsky and Partners', 'Serhal Nassar &amp; Co', 'SGLA Law Firm', 'Shahrul Hamidi &amp; Haziq Advocates &amp; Solicitors', 'ShawnCoulson', "Sherwin O'Riordan solicitors", 'Shibolet Law Firm', 'Shiff &amp; Company', 'Shihui Partners', 'Shimuta Law Firm', 'Shook Lin &amp; Bok', 'Shustak Reynolds &amp; Partners, P.C', 'Sikich Investment Banking', 'Singhania &amp; Partners LLP', 'Sino Group', 'Sintes Law Firm', 'Siskind Susser PC', 'Skinner Clouse Group', 'SKJERVE-NIELSSEN &amp; CO ADVOKATFIRMA', 'Sklar Williams PLLC', 'SKW Schwarz Rechtsanwälte', 'SLG Shelowitz Law Group', 'SLJ Abogados', 'Smith Haughey Rice &amp; Roegee', 'Smith, Katzenstein &amp; Jenkins LLP', 'SMTD Law LLP', 'Snoeker Advocatuur', 'Sola Oyetayo &amp; Co.', 'Solak &amp; Partners', 'SOMNUK SUTEE &amp; ASSOCIATES LIMITED', 'SOTH Rechtsanwälte', 'Sotomonte, Sotomonte &amp; Rodríguez', 'Sourced Research &amp; Consulting GmbH', 'Spa Azzouz Audit &amp; Tax Firm', 'Spencer West LLP', 'SPK Auditors &amp; Accountants', 'SPL Audit (Cyprus) Limited', 'Stephen Vivian SC', 'Strachn Law', 'Strategic Wealth Management Pty Ltd', 'Strategio', 'STROLLA', 'Studio Avella', 'Studio Bongiorni', 'Studio Carlo Veronese', 'Studio Legale Gentiloni Silveri', 'Studio Marco Arisi Rota', 'Studio Micaglio', 'SUMALEGAL', 'Summit Law Corporation', 'Sundgaard Advokater', 'Super Audits', 'Swarup &amp; Company', 'Synergy Attornies', 'Synergy Business Lawyers', 'Taft', 'Tailored Tax Solutions', 'TALG', 'TAUTSCHNIG Rechtsanwälte GmbH', 'Taylor &amp; Blair LLP', 'Taylor English Duma', 'The Antonio Maria Varvaro &amp; Fulvio Pardu Law Firm', 'The Bellows Law Group, P.C.', 'The Law Office of L. Forrest Owens, P.A. DBA Aviation Legal Counsel', 'The Law Offices of Jean-Charles S. Gardetto', 'The Rodes Firm PLLC', 'The Swafford Law', 'The Torrey Firm', 'THOMAS M. LANCIA PLLC', 'Thorbergsson &amp; Loftsdottir law firm', 'Threshing Fields - Solicitors &amp; Advocates', 'TIC Assurance', 'TJ Kelly Intellectual Property Law, PC', 'TKC finance &amp; consulting', 'TL Partners – Tax &amp; Legal Partners Studio Legale Tributario', 'TMT Law Practice', 'TND Legal', 'Toha Khan Zaman &amp; Co. Chartered Accountants', 'Tonkin Clacey Inc', 'Torkin Manes LLP', 'Torres Legal', 'Transfer Pricing Specialists', 'Traple Konarski Podrecki &amp; Wspólnicy', 'TREJOS, EGAN &amp; ASOCIADOS', 'Treuco', 'Troller Hitz Troller', 'Truter Jones inc', 'Tucker Ellis LLP', 'Tuerlinckx Tax Lawyers', 'UGGC Avocats', 'United Advocates', 'Urso, Liguori &amp; Micklich', 'Urus Advisory', 'Vaas Chartered Accountants Inc.', 'Vaia Legal', 'Valadas Coriel &amp; Associados', 'Valentina Arnez, LL.M.', 'Valinvest', 'Value Plus CPA Limited', 'VALUESQUE', 'Vantru', 'Vasil &amp; Partners', 'VCvF.legal', 'Venetucci &amp; Asociados', 'Vera Law (Del Rosario Raboca Gonzales Grasparil)', 'Vernon | David', 'Vertess', 'Vienna Legal Group - Cooperation of Independent Lawyers', 'Villaraza &amp; Angangco Law', 'Virtual CA', 'Vlock &amp; Associates, P.C.', 'Voelkl Rechtsanwälte GmbH &amp; Co KG', 'Voisin Law', 'Voloaga', 'W.A. Kareem Chartered Accountants', 'WaBuCo Financial Services Oy', 'Wade Clark Mulcahy', 'Wakefield Quin Limited', 'Wallace Corporate Counsel LLP', 'WALLISON &amp; WALLISON LLP', 'Walser &amp; Partner AG', 'WARBEK Attorneys at Law', 'WardChisholm, LLP', 'Warshaw Burstein, LLP', 'Watanabe Ing LLP', 'WDM International', 'Weaver', 'Weber &amp; Sauberschwarz', 'Wedlake Bell', 'WEIL &amp; ASSOCIÉS', 'Welsh IP Law, LLC', 'WH &amp; CO', 'Whitehall Workplace Law', 'Wicki Partners AG', 'Wilder Coe Ltd', 'William Nyirenda &amp; Company', 'WN Law', 'Wolfgang Kaltenegger Consult GmbH', 'Wolfs Advocaten', 'Wong Fleming', 'WP Thompson', 'Yodoyabashi &amp; Yamagami LPC', 'Yokogi &amp; Masui Partners', 'You Are Capital', 'Zæhringen Attorneys', 'Zang, Bergel &amp; Viñes Abogados', 'Zayas, Morazzani &amp; Co', 'Zell, Aron &amp; Co.', 'Zemp Law Group', 'Zirkzee Group', 'ZVMLaw']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hello - thanks a lot - works great
(i was not aware that i have to click first on the select box and only after that the options  for the selectbox can be seen in the html-code - so i was also able to first click the select box with ´waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="select2-firm-container"]'))).click() ´ and then get the option values with beautiful soap)